# splot 3D plots with equal scale on x, y, z

Tags: plot, gnuplot

The splot function from gnuplot that I use shows different scales of x, y and z axis. So, the final plot is often stretched along one axis. How could I specify that I want equal scale along all three axis?

I read that 'set size square' does the job in 2D, but I wonder how could this be achieved with splot (3D).

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Great question!

I think you want `set view equal xyz`.  (see `help view equal`)

Comment: even though manual agrees with it I still get result: `undefined variable: equal`

Comment: @sluki, to me it works just fine. Perhaps you have an outdated/bugged version of `gnuplot`...

Comment: @mgilson, thanks but do known how to stop the plot "hovering", i.e how to reduce the distance to the xy plane?

Comment: @CastleDefender try `set xyplane relative 0` to set the xy-plane at z-min.

Comment: @CastleDefender 'set ticslevel 0'